sqlalchemy none value will be ignored when update a associate list
I have two models like that:
class Parent(db.Model):
  ...
  children = db.relationship(Child,  cascade="all,delete-orphan")

class Child(db.Model):
  a = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True, , db.ForeignKey('Parent.id'))
  b = db.Column(db.String())
  c = db.Column(db.String())


parent = Parent.query.get(xxx)
parent.children = [Child(a=123, b="b", c=None), ...]
db.session.add(parent)
db.session.flush()


If the database already has a child record with a=123, the above code will trigger an update statement like this: update child set b='b' where a=123.
The problem is that it can't update the value of c to null, c=None will be ignored.
I use flask-sqlalchemy 2.4.0 and sqlalchemy 1.3.8.
How can I update it to null?
In addition, if the database has no record with a=123, the code will trigger an insert SQL, the none value will be successfully inserted.

It doesn't usually make sense to use a primary key as a foreign key. That means there's a 1-to-1 relationship between the two tables, and you can't have multiple children of the same parent.

Asked and answered on GitHub here

thank for the answer of Gord Thompson in github. Sorry, I did a minimal demo for test, and I did not reproduce the same problem, but it does exist in the actual program, so it is probably caused by other parts of the program. I will do another experiment to confirm where the problem lies before asking questions.

I found the answer:
if i Explicitly define the value of "c", like this, it will update.
parent.children = [Child(a=123, b="b", c=None), ...]
but if I just use the default none value of "c", it will not update, the original value will remain unchanged.
parent.children = [Child(a=123, b="b"), ...]

Your answer makes no sense to me: in the question you said that c=None doesn't work, while here you say that c=None does. Could you please clarify this?

@Wolf in my real usage, I did not assign values ​​to all the none values, but just skipped them. like this: child = Child() child.a=123.  now the child.c is None， but it will not be updated.
